# Jquery Mobile button not shown text value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-mobile

I am using Asp.net and Mobile jquery in my project. I wanna buttons text change in Clicking Up And Down buttons. Its working perfectly in System Chrome Browser. But my mobile browser - opera mobile, Its not show the Text.(Buttons are Blank even Up and Down Also Not Display.) What is mistake?.

I hope you will understand my problem. I give my code below for reference...

**ASPX -**

```
<div id="body" class="ui-content ui-body-a" > 
        <div class="ui-grid-b">                
            <div class="ui-block-a"><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" /></div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"> <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" /></div>             
            <div class="ui-block-c"> <asp:Button ID="btnUp" runat="server" Text="UP" onclick="btnUp_Click" /></div>    
            <div class="ui-block-a"><asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button" /></div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"><asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Button" /></div>
            <div class="ui-block-c"> <asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" Text="Button" /></div>
            <div class="ui-block-a"><asp:Button ID="Button6" runat="server" Text="Button" /></div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"><asp:Button ID="Button7" runat="server" Text="Button" /></div>
            <div class="ui-block-c"> <asp:Button ID="Button8" runat="server" Text="Button" /></div>
            <div class="ui-block-a"><asp:Button ID="Button9" runat="server" Text="Button" /></div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"><asp:Button ID="Button10" runat="server" Text="Button" /></div>                       
            <div class="ui-block-c"><asp:Button ID="btnDown" runat="server" Text="DOWN" onclick="btnDown_Click" /></div>               
        </div><!-- /grid-b -->
```

**C#**

```
  public int btn_click, tot;
        string[] roomno = new string[100];
        int i = 0;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(GlobalClass.GlobalConnString.ToString());
            //string query = "SELECT Table_Entry_TableNo FROM fb_table_entry where Table_entry_OutletId ='"+ GlobalClass.GlobaloutletId +"' and Table_Entry_DeleteStatus = '0' order by CAST(Table_Entry_TableNo AS UNSIGNED),  Table_Entry_TableNo";
            //MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            //connection.Open();
            //MySqlDataReader Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            //while (Reader.Read())
            //{

            //}
            //connection.Close();
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                ViewState["btn"] = "1";
                ViewState["tot"] = "0";               
                btn_click = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["btn"].ToString());

                int vallen = 45;
                int len = vallen;
                while (len > 10)
                {
                    len = len - 10;
                    tot++;
                }

                if (len != 0) tot++;

                ViewState["tot"] = tot;

                for (int j = 0; j <= vallen; j++)
                {
                    roomno[j] = "A" + Convert.ToString(j + 1);
                }

                ViewState["roomno"] = roomno;
                //i = 20;
                fun();
            }

        }

        private void fun()
        {
            btn_click = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["btn"].ToString());

            i = 10 * (btn_click);

            roomno = ViewState["roomno"] as string[];
            Button1.Text = roomno[i - 10];
            Button2.Text = roomno[i - 9];
            Button3.Text = roomno[i - 8];
            Button4.Text = roomno[i - 7];
            Button5.Text = roomno[i - 6];
            Button6.Text = roomno[i - 5];
            Button7.Text = roomno[i - 4];
            Button8.Text = roomno[i - 3];
            Button9.Text = roomno[i - 2];
            Button10.Text = roomno[i - 1];         
            //enabledFn();
        }

        private void enabledFn()
        {
            //var buttons = this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<Button>();
            //foreach (var button in buttons)
            //{
            //    if (button.Text != "")
            //    {
            //        button.Enabled = true;
            //    }
            //    else
            //    {
            //        button.Enabled = false;
            //    }
            //}
        }

        protected void btnUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tot = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["tot"].ToString());
            btn_click = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["btn"].ToString());
            if (btn_click != 1) { btn_click--; ViewState["btn"] = btn_click; fun(); }            
            Button1.Text = Convert.ToString(btn_click);            
        }

        protected void btnDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tot = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["tot"].ToString());
            btn_click = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["btn"].ToString());
            if (btn_click < tot) { btn_click++; ViewState["btn"] = btn_click; fun(); }           
            Button1.Text = Convert.ToString(btn_click);            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Find The Button Style code in js files. I think,.. The Buttons are have the text, but it may be swing or collapsed. Try that in various browser and Tiled the Mobile and See Whether It seems the text or not?.